# How to spread an infected node to its adjacent nodes and eventually to the whole binary tree?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I want to iteratively return the state of the binary tree until the infection is unable to spread to a new node. So how it goes is that the virus will spread to any directly adjacent healthy node and I want to return the state of the tree every after round of infections the virus does. Once every possible node is infected, the algorithm should stop.

What I want to achieve given that "B" is the origin (Example):

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
from binarytree import Node, build

def build_tree(data):
    if not data or data[0] == 0:
        return None
    root = Node(data[0])
    nodes = [root]
    for i in range(1, len(data), 2):
        node = nodes.pop(0)
        if data[i] != 0:
            node.left = Node(data[i])
            nodes.append(node.left)
        if i + 1 < len(data) and data[i + 1] != 0:
            node.right = Node(data[i + 1])
            nodes.append(node.right)
    return root
    
def infected(node):
    return f"*{node.value}*"

def search_node(root, value):
    if root is None or root.value == value:
        return root
    left_result = search_node(root.left, value)
    right_result = search_node(root.right, value)
    return left_result if left_result else right_result

def virus(node):
    infected_nodes = set()
    current_round = set([node])

    while current_round:
        next_round = set()

        for current_node in current_round:
            neighbors = [child for child in (current_node.left, current_node.right) if child and child.value != 0]

            for neighbor in neighbors:
                if neighbor not in infected_nodes:
                    infected_nodes.add(neighbor)
                    neighbor.value = infected(neighbor)
                    next_round.add(neighbor)

        if infected_nodes == set(current_round):
           break

        print(tree)
        current_round = next_round
```

Input:

```
sample = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 0, "F"]
origin_value = "C"

tree = build_tree(sample)
origin_node = search_node(tree, origin_value)

origin_node.value = infected(origin_node)
print(tree)
virus(origin_node)
```

Output:

[image]

As seen from the output, C only spreads to F and it stops there, where it should have spread to A and to the entirety of the binary tree. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: You seem to be doing wrong that you don't visit parent nodes properly.

Comment: Perhaps I should create a class that extends the Node class and add a parent attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is modified version of the code, using `.inorder` function to traverse the tree. Also, I've added `.infected` boolean parameter to each node signaling if the Node is infected or not:

```py
from binarytree import Node, build


def build_tree(data):
    nodes = []
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        if v == 0:
            nodes.append(None)
        else:
            n = Node(v)
            n.infected = False  # <-- node is initailly *NOT* infected
            nodes.append(n)

    for i in range(len(data)):
        left = 2 * i + 1
        right = 2 * i + 2

        if left < len(nodes) and nodes[left]:
            nodes[i].left = nodes[left]

        if right < len(nodes) and nodes[right]:
            nodes[i].right = nodes[right]

    return nodes[0]


def is_whole_tree_infected(root):
    return all(n.infected for n in root.inorder)


def search_node(root, value):
    for n in root.inorder:
        if n.value == value:
            return n


def find_parent(root, node):
    for n in root.inorder:
        if n.left is node:
            return n
        if n.right is node:
            return n


def infect(node):
    node.value = f"*{node.value}*"
    node.infected = True


def infect_neighbours(root, node):
    out = set()
    parent = find_parent(root, node)
    if parent and not parent.infected:
        out.add(parent)
    if node.left and not node.left.infected:
        out.add(node.left)
    if node.right and not node.right.infected:
        out.add(node.right)

    return out


def virus(root):
    while not is_whole_tree_infected(root):
        to_infect = set()

        for node in root.inorder:
            if node.infected:
                to_infect |= infect_neighbours(root, node)

        for n in to_infect:
            infect(n)

        print(root)


sample = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 0, "F"]
origin_value = "C"

tree = build_tree(sample)
origin_node = search_node(tree, origin_value)
infect(origin_node)

print(tree)
virus(tree)
```

Prints:

```
    __A_
   /    \
  B     *C*
 / \       \
D   E       F


    __*A*_
   /      \
  B       *C*_
 / \          \
D   E         *F*


     ___*A*_
    /       \
  *B*       *C*_
 /   \          \
D     E         *F*


       _____*A*_
      /         \
   _*B*_        *C*_
  /     \           \
*D*     *E*         *F*
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have already solved it, but this is shorter than the method I did. I made a class that has a parent attribute and did the same thing here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each node has access to its own parent, the top level algorithm is a breadth first traversal startnig at the origin node, then repeat that algorithm on the parent node

```
Infect the origin node and put that node in a single element list called "the list"

while the list is not empty:
    infect all nodes in the list
    print the tree, as this represents the next iteration
    Update the list to contain all the children of the current list
    
After the above algorithm runs, move up the parent node of the origin node and repeat.
```

I think this is close to what you want:

```
def virus(tree, originNode):
    while True:
        startInfectingDownward(tree, originNode)
        if not originNode.parent:
            break
        originNode = originNode.parent

def startInfectingDownward(tree, originNode):
    if (originNode.isInfected):
        return
    nextSetOfInfections = [originNode]
    while nextSetOfInfections:
       for node in nextSetOfInfections:
           node.isInfected = true
       printTree(tree)
       nextSetOfInfections = getNextSetOfInfections(nextSetOfInfections)


def getNextSetOfInfections(list):
    resultList = []
    for item in list:
       if (item.left and not item.left.isInfected):
           resultList.append(item.left)
       if (item.right and not item.right.isInfected):
           resultList.append(item.right)
    return resultList
```

Answer (score 0):

As neighbors of a node you should also consider the *parent* of that node. The `binarytree` package exposes a `get_parent` function, so that's easy.

Some other remarks:

- Don't use 0 as indication for the absence of a node. Use `None` instead: the `build` function exposed by `binarytree` will take that into account, and this makes your own `build_tree` function obsolete.
- Although your code marks the original node as infected (by adding asterisks to its value), you didn't add this node to the `infected_nodes` set, making the situation inconsistent. I would suggest avoiding such errors and replacing the `infected` function by an `infect` function that does *all* that is needed to infect a node. It will *set* the `value` and add an attribute `is_infected` to replace the use of a set for this purpose.
- `virus` has an access to the `tree` variable, which is global. This is not good practice, and would become problematic if you would have multiple trees to work with. Pass `tree` as argument to `virus`.
- The exit condition `if infected_nodes == set(current_round)` can better be left out: just let the `while` condition do its work.
- The nodes in a `binarytree` tree are iterable, i.e. when you iterate such a node, you'll get that node and all its descendants in level order. You can use this feature to greatly simplify your `search_node` function.

Here is your code updated:

```
from binarytree import build, get_parent

def infect(node):  # Do all that is needed to mark a node as infected
    node.is_infected = True  # This seems more elegant than maintaining a set
    node.value = f"*{node.value}*"

def search_node(root, value):
    # The nodes are iterable, so make use of that feature
    return next(node for node in root if node.value == value)

def virus(tree, node):  # Extra argument, so we can find the parent of a node
    infect(origin_node)  # Perform the first infection inside virus()
    current_round = set([node])
    while current_round:
        print(tree)
        next_round = set()
        for current_node in current_round:
            # The node's parent is also a neighbor: 
            #    use the get_parent function from the package
            for neighbor in current_node.left, current_node.right,
                                               get_parent(tree, current_node):
                # Use of an "is_infected" attribute works fine
                if neighbor and not hasattr(neighbor, "is_infected"):
                    infect(neighbor)
                    next_round.add(neighbor)
        current_round = next_round

# Use None to indicate the absence of a node (not 0)
sample = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", None, "F"]
origin_value = "C"
tree = build(sample)  # Use build() from binarytree package
origin_node = search_node(tree, origin_value)
virus(tree, origin_node)  # Pass tree as argument
```